# Spotlight shows web sugggestions despite disabling it

Tags: mac, macos, spotlight

I disabled spotlight suggestions like recommended on the web (e.g. [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/224344/how-to-disable-spotlights-web-searches-on-mac-iphone-and-ipad/)). My settings now look like this:

System Preferences:
[image: System Preferenes]
Safari Preferences
[image: Safari Preferences]

However, I still get website suggestions for spotlight searches:
[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This trick is working for me with yosemite .I did unload the SpotlightNetHelper service using the terminal with this command `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.metadata.SpotlightNetHelper.plist` and then reboot

Comment: hm, I get "/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.metadata.SpotlightNetHelper.plist: Could not find specified service" when I try to run this on el capitan. The plist file exists though

Comment: It is kind of a long shot but you can rename the app : sudo mv /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ParsecUI.framework/Versions/A/Support/SpotlightNetHelper.app /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ParsecUI.framework/Versions/A/Support/SpotlightNetHelper.app.backup

Comment: if the .plist exist an you get "/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.metadata.SpotlightNetHelper.plist: Could not find specified service" it probably  means that the service is already unloaded you can check by loading it sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.metadata.SpotlightNetHelper.plist

Comment: After a reboot it worked... No Idea though why id did not already work after unloading the service.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce, but here are a few ideas:

- try to change the settings once again:

  1. check "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Spotlight and Look up"
  2. uncheck "Spotlight suggestions" in the list
  3. uncheck "Allow
     Spotlight Suggestions in Spotlight and Look up"
- delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Spotlight.plist`, reboot and configure again via System Preferences

Comment: Do you have a `Spotlight Suggestions` line to select within your list on `El Capitan`?

Comment: Yes, but only when "Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Spotlight and Look up" is checked.